# FilterPattern for AWS cloud watch subscription filter

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I've two log lines, which I want to fetch.

First log -

`2022-11-02 request sent => [xxxx........`

Second log -

`2022-11-02 res received => [xxxx........`

So I've applied the following filter pattern on console and tested it, it worked fine. - `?"request sent " ?"res received"`.

But when I give the same filter patten on the `yaml` configuration file, it throws an error while deploying...

I have tried

`FilterPattern: ?"request sent " ?"res received`  & `FilterPattern: '?"request sent " ?"res received'`. But it's not working. What is the proper way of writing it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape double quotes

```yaml
FilterPattern: ?\"request sent \" ?\"res received\"
```

or

```yaml
FilterPattern: "?\"request sent \" ?\"res received\""
```

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html#matching-terms-events